# Developing a paint application in Adobe flash builder

Tags: apache-flex, graphics, adobe, air, paint

Can any one provide me some good resource for getting started with Graphics API in adobe flash builder?

Regards,
Abdul khaliq

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is «Flex 4 Fun» book from Chet Haase about graphics and animation on flex platform. Simple [chapter](http://www.artima.com/samples/flex4funCh2.pdf) introduces sample [application](http://booksites.artima.com/flex_4_fun/apps/) Shapely which show drawing basics in Flex 4.